# Most efficient way to remove multiple items from a IList<T>

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, ilist

What is the most efficient way to remove multiple items from an `IList<T>` object. Suppose I have an `IEnumerable<T>` of all the items I want to remove, in the same order of occurrence that in the original list.

The only way I have in mind is:

```
IList<T> items;
IEnumerable<T> itemsToDelete;
...

foreach (var x in itemsToDelete)
{
    items.Remove(x);
}
```

But I guess it's not efficient, because it has to go over the list from the beggining every time the method `Remove` is called.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? how much performance improvement do you need?

Comment: As John Skeet says: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: It because I work with many lists, and I will have to do it many times.

Comment: Computer's can usually do things "many times" very quickly.  Are you sure there is even a performance issue here?

Comment: Is `items` in order? Is `itemsToDelete` in order? Have you considered if you can use an `ISet` for fast exclusions? Have you benchmarked creating a new list instead of editing one in place with `var set = new HashSet<T>(itemsToDelete); var newList = items.Where(i => !set.Contains(i)).ToList();`? Have you benchmarked at all?

Comment: Both could be not ordered, but both have the same order of appearance. I can't create a new List, because I don't know if the IList<T> instance is actually a List<T>, and maybe the underlying libraries that use it has a custom implementation of IList<T>, not List<T>. And no, I didn't have benchmarked at all. Could not be a significant performance issue, but as some teacher once said me: "It's just for the sake of my own soul".

Comment: *but as some teacher once said me: "It's just for the sake of my own soul"* Yes and [a wiser teacher said "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the number of items to remove gets larger, you will probably find traversing the list and checking each item against a hashset of "items to remove" is more efficient. An extension method like this might help:

```
static void RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> iList, IEnumerable<T> itemsToRemove)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>(itemsToRemove);

    var list = iList as List<T>;
    if (list == null)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < iList.Count)
        {
            if (set.Contains(iList[i])) iList.RemoveAt(i);
            else i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        list.RemoveAll(set.Contains);
    }
}
```

I benchmarked using this little program below. (Note that it uses an optimized path if `IList<T>` is actually a `List<T>`.)

On my machine (and using my test data), this extention method took **1.5 seconds** to execute vs **17 seconds** for the code in your question. However, I have not tested with different sizes of data. I'm sure for removing just a couple of items `RemoveAll2` will be faster.

```
static class Program
{
    static void RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> iList, IEnumerable<T> itemsToRemove)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<T>(itemsToRemove);

        var list = iList as List<T>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < iList.Count)
            {
                if (set.Contains(iList[i])) iList.RemoveAt(i);
                else i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list.RemoveAll(set.Contains);
        }
    }

    static void RemoveAll2<T>(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> itemsToRemove)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
            list.Remove(item);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).ToList();
        var toRemove = new[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 
                              43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101,
                             103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167,
                             173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239,
                             241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313,
                             317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397,
                             401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467,
                             479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569,
                             571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643,
                             647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733,
                             739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823,
                             827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911,
                             919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997};
        list.RemoveAll(toRemove); // JIT 
        //list.RemoveAll2(toRemove); // JIT 

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            list.RemoveAll(toRemove);
            //list.RemoveAll2(toRemove);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE** (for @KarmaEDV's & Mark Sowul's comments below):
If you need to use a custom equality comparer, the extension method could have an overload that takes such a comparer:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> iList, IEnumerable<T> itemsToRemove, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>(itemsToRemove, comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default);

    if (iList is List<T>)
    {
        list.RemoveAll(set.Contains);
    }
    else
    {
        int i = iList.Count - 1;
        while (i > -1)
        {
            if (set.Contains(iList[i])) iList.RemoveAt(i);
            else i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend iterating through the list in the opposite order.  If you remove the first item from the list, you have to shift all the remaining items.  It's more efficient to remove from back to front.

Comment: This solution is great, but the optimized List-Path doesn't work reliably if the List overrides the Contains Method.

Comment: @KarmaEDV could you maybe clarify? [List<T>.RemoveAll](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html#82567b42bbfc416e) doesn't call into Contains, and you can't  override Contains since it's not `virtual`.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Im not sure what you mean with "doesnt call into Contains". Yes, sorry, not override, but overload.  IEnumerable<T>.Contains(item, customComparer) is an overload if you need a custom comparer. If you use that you need to slightly adapt the proposed solution.

Comment: @KarmaEDV If understand you, yes, you would need a slight modification in case you need to use a custom comparer.  I've posted such a variant in the answer.

Comment: Small improvement: Run the list form behind, this saves the most copy operations when multiple elements are removed.

Answer (score 7):

If the `IList<T>` reference happens to refer to an instance of `List<T>`, casting to that type and using `RemoveAll` is apt to yield better performance than any other approach that doesn't rely upon the particulars of its implementation.

Otherwise, while the optimal approach will depend upon the relative fraction of items that are going to be removed and the nature of the `IList<T>`, I would suggest that your best bet might be to copy the `IList<T>` to a new `List<T>`, clear it, and selectively re-add items.  Even if the items in the list are not conducive to efficient hashing, the fact that the items in the `IEnumerable<T>` are in the same sequence as those in the `IList<T>` would render that irrelevant.  Start by reading an item from the `IEnumerable<T>`.  Then copy items from the array to the list until that one is found.  Then read the next item from the `IEnumerable<T>` and copy from the array to the list until that one is found, etc.  Once the `IEnumerable<T>` is exhausted, copy the balance of the array to the `List<T>`.

This approach will be fast with many implementations of `IList<T>`.  It has one major disadvantage, though: the fact that it deletes and re-adds each item might have unwanted side-effects on things like observable lists.  If a list might be observable, one may have to use a much slower N^2 algorithm to ensure correctness.  [BTW, it irks me that `IList<T>` has a `Remove(T)` method but lacks a much more useful `RemoveAll(Func<T,bool>)` method.  The `Remove(T)` is largely redundant with `IndexOf` and `RemoveAt`, while `RemoveAll` would allow O(N) implementations of many operations that are O(N^2) in its absence if one isn't allowed to remove and re-add items.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps. Other ideas of the same type could be included.

```
IList<T> items;

IEnumerable<T> itemsToDelete;
...
{
   if(items.Equals(itemsToDelete)) //Equal lists?
     {
      items.Clear(); 
      return true;
     }


   if(  (double) items.Count/itemsToDelete.Count < 1){
      /* It is faster to iterate the small list first. */ 
              foreach (var x in items)
              {
                if(itemsToDelete.Contains(x)){/**/} 

              }
    }
   else{
           foreach (var x in itemsToDelete)
              {
               items.Remove(x);
              }
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try comparing `items.Count < itemsToDelete.Count()` rather than using `double`s. Also it avoids a compiler error.

Comment: I didn't put the explanation: the division is in case you want a percentage close: you could replace the 1 for .9 for 90%.

Answer (score 0):

This problem would be easier to solve if there was available an extension method `RemoveAll` for the [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1) interface. So here is one:

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the
/// specified predicate.
/// </summary>
public static int RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, int, bool> predicate)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(list);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(predicate);

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    try
    {
        for (; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (predicate(list[i], i)) continue;
            if (j < i) list[j] = list[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (j < i)
        {
            for (; i < list.Count; i++, j++)
                list[j] = list[i];
            while (list.Count > j)
                list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
        }
    }
    return i - j;
}
```

This is a modified version of a custom `List<T>.RemoveAll` implementation that is found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027446/how-to-implement-a-specialized-overload-of-the-list-removeall-method-with-an-in/75039907#75039907). Because of the absence of the [`RemoveRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange) method in the `IList<T>` interface, the rightmost leftover slots in the `IList<T>` are cleared with repeated removals of the last element. This should be a pretty fast operation in most `IList<T>` implementations.

Now the original problem of removing multiple items from a `IList<T>` can be solved efficiently like this:

```
IList<T> items;
IEnumerable<T> itemsToDelete;
//...

HashSet<T> itemsToDeleteSet = new(itemsToDelete);
items.RemoveAll((x, _) => itemsToDeleteSet.Contains(x));
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jU6Glj).